# Get Windows Username during SSH connection

Tags: python, ssh

I have a python app that runs on an SSH connection through MobaXTerm. Many people use the app, the current version has each one log in with a username & password. I am trying to skip the login process all together and just have a list of authorized users' windows login usernames. The only ways I know how to retrieve the username will return the username of the current SSH connection which is the same for everyone. Is there a way to get the Windows username during an SSH connection?

```
os.getlogin()

os.path.expanduser('~')

os.environ.get('USERNAME')

getpass.getuser()

pwd.getpwuid(os.getuid())[0]
```

These all return the SSH username. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: would os.system('whoami') work?

Comment: The problem is the command is being sent through a remote connection so that would still return the remote username.